# Bootstrap Progressbar color in datatables wont work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, progress-bar

Got a problem I really cant understand.

I use DataTables in which a column a bootstrap progressbar is displayed. It all works, I can make it striped and all but the damn color wont change to the class of my choosing.

```
{
    "mData": "BudgetProgress",
    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {

                    if(full['SumBudget'] == null ){

                        return "0";
                        }
                    else{

                    var pr = (full['TotalSum'] / full['SumBudget'] * 100).toFixed(0);
                    return "<div style='height:10px'><div class='progress'><div class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success' role='progressbar' style='width: "+pr+"%;' aria-valuenow='"+pr+"' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'>"+pr+"%</div></div></div>";
                    }
            }
        }
```

And the interesting part is:

```
<div class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success'
```

Why won't the damn bar turn green?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped"
```

Comment: How good it would be, if there was a bit of description, Please check [writing a good answer- S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), You're [welcome to S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) though

Comment: Agreed with @irf

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify attributes after datatables are rendered.